# Material-react-table get Filtered data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I want to get filtered that in rendered in other component(There i am showing markers in map) but there is no way i find to get filtered data in material-react-table. I just want to set data in state when ever some data changes in table.
[Here is my try](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-rgb-x7sne5?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.map(row => row.original)`

to get all of the data that is present after a filter has been applied.